# Flutter App Firebase push notification not coming in background

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing issue received notifications when app terminated/Remove from recent apps from background.

I have complete all the setup required for android app in build.gradle files both app or project level. I am able to receive push notification when app is open or when app is in the recent apps.

Library versions

```
firebase_messaging: ^11.2.0
firebase_core: ^1.10.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.4
```

here is my code.

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

```
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    messaging.getToken().then((value) {
      print('firebase token =$value');    
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      //print(event.notification!.body);
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      if (notification != null) {
        print("Notification received when app in foreground");
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      print('Message clicked!');
    });

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
```

BackgroundMessage handler code is below

```
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  if (notification != null) {
    print("Notification received when app in background");
  }
}
```

Below is my complete code of main.dart file

```
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  if (notification != null) {
    print("Notification received when app in background");
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isUserLoggedIn = true;
  bool isLogoutAlertShown = false;
  final materialAppKey = GlobalKey();
  late FirebaseMessaging messaging;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setUpNotification();
  }

  setUpNotification() async {
    messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    messaging.getToken().then((value) {
      print('firebase token =$value');
      //sendTokenToServer(value);
      Pref.setFcmToken(token: '$value');
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      //print(event.notification!.body);
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      if (notification != null) {
        print("Notification received when app in foreground");
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      print('Message clicked!');
    });
   await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _materialApp();
  }

  Widget _materialApp() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _loginState(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              key: materialAppKey,
              darkTheme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
              theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
              home: isUserLoggedIn == true ? 
              BottomNavigationContainer() : LoginOptions(),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(color: Colors.white);
          }
        });
  }

  Future<void> _loginState() async {
    final token = await Pref.getToken();
    isUserLoggedIn = token.length > 0 ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Suggest me what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Add main.dart file code.

Comment: main.dart file code update @Yashraj

Comment: Add this line in main() : 

 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler);

Comment: Added but still not working when i remove the app from recent app. @Yashraj

Comment: At least on Android this requires an implementation of `MessagingService` ...which is white-listed, in order to be able to run in the background (even when `Activity` is not running). While I'd assume this to be a likely duplicate Q, without having searched ...the assumption, that an app which is not running, could handle a background message, makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please suggest me how to implement this service. so i can receive notification in background when app is not running. @MartinZeitler

Comment: Check the "developer options" in the "settings", then "Running services", then in the menu "show cached processes" and check if your app is there.

Comment: If the processe is there, there is no problem. What are you doing in background? I just see a print. The print won't work when the app is close.

Comment: thanks for your response. I check the settings also it's working. 

For background message we just need to add background method flutter automatically generate notification if we added this method. @mariofrancois

Comment: Can you restart your android once and check again

Comment: I Already checked this by restarting my android device.@HardikMehta

Comment: Have you tried in another devices?
Which device are you using?

Comment: I have tried on 3 different device and versions. Redmi note 9 (Version 10),Redmi Note 8 (Version 11) and Oppo A5 (Version 9) @Yashraj

Comment: So the issue maybe is in missing some configuration part.
add your gradle files here.

Comment: Did you try creating a NotificationChannel? Check this Medium post: https://rechor.medium.com/creating-notification-channels-in-flutter-android-e81e26b33bec

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank to all for your response.

I Found the solution that why my background handler not working because I am running my app in Debugging mode. As per the [FlutterFire Cloud messaging Doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages)   background method not work in Debugging mode if you kill your app.

You can test your background handler method by run your application in debug and then background it by switching apps so it's no longer in the foreground.

If You want to check After app terminate/kill from recent task then Run app in **Release Mode**. It Works fine

Again thanks to All.

Comment: another way is open app again and close it, hence it will work as terminated app.

Comment: The actual question is,, Not getting notification when app in background, What is the correct solution?...we did all area,,, we need to know if anyone missing,, Its causing not only in debug mode also in release mode

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add under given line in the server-side body of the notification.
"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
and the postman json is:
`{ "to": "foP947GMRmuin1N********************", "priority": "high", "notification": { "title": "Sakib sent a offer", "body": "An electric bike used 2 years", "android_channel_id": "Messages", "count": 10, "notification_count": 12, "badge": 12, "color": "#eeeeee" }, "data": { "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "type": "msj", "id": "1" } }`

And in your manifest just add following code:
`<intent-filter> <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter>`